# What is a remote table in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle19c

What is a remote table in Oracle? For example, are the tables in different pluggable databases but at the same container considered as remote tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally anything that needs to be accessed via a database link is considered "remote".  Pluggable databases make that a little more 'vague' in that you still need a database link to go between them, but there are clauses such as the CONTAINERS() clause which lets you span multiple pluggables and the like.